# Issues with states not updating correctly in React/Django

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Building a site where users upload images/video, in the component that handles that, I have the images load into the page after being uploaded, so that the user can make sure they want to post them, and have the option to remove them if they like.  I originally had this as a Class-based view, and everything worked as expected, but now, after changing to a functional component, after uploading images, React doesn't seem to notice the changes to imageLinks (even though the console shows that imageLinks is getting added to), until I update something else like the post title, then they all load in as expected.  Once loaded in, if I click the delete button, React instantly updates and the photos/videos no longer shows up, as expected.

Any ideas as to why this is behaving so oddly?
The fact that the deleteMedia function works just fine is what really weirds me out.

I set up my variables like this

```
export default function NewPost(props) {
  const [postCategories, setPostCategories] = useState([]);
  const [postTitle, setPostTitle] = useState();
  const [postDescription, setPostDescription] = useState();
  const [postHashtags, setPostHashtags] = useState();
  const [imageLinks, setImageLinks] = useState([]);
...}
```

In my component, I have this to handle uploading and deleting files.

```
const uploadMedia = async (file) => {
    var csrftoken = getCookie("csrftoken");
    var media_id = makeMediaID();
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("content_id", contentID);
    formData.append("creator_id", USER_ADDRESS);
    formData.append("content_media", file);
    formData.append("media_id", media_id);
    const response = await fetch("/api/newpost/media/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
      },
      body: formData,
    });
    console.log(response);
    const r_json = await response.json();
    if (r_json.success) {
      let tempLinks = imageLinks;
      tempLinks.push({
        img: r_json.image_url,
        id: r_json.m_id,
        type: r_json.m_type,
      });
      setImageLinks(tempLinks);
      console.log(imageLinks);
    } else {
      console.log(r_json.message);
    }
  };
  
  const deleteMedia = async (media) => {
    var csrftoken = getCookie("csrftoken");
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("media_id", media);
    formData.append("creator_id", USER_ADDRESS);
    const response = await fetch("/api/newpost/media/delete/", {
      method: "DELETE",
      headers: {
        "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
      },
      body: formData,
    });
    console.log(response);
    const r_json = await response.json();
    if (r_json.success) {
      let tempLinks = imageLinks.filter((item) => item.id !== media);
      setImageLinks(tempLinks);
    } else {
      console.log("Media deletion error");
    }
  };
```

And in my render, I have this, which worked just fine when it was a class-based component.

```
{imageLinks.map((item) => (
                  <Grid item xs={9} align="center" key={item.img}>
                    <Card style={{ maxWidth: 550, margin: 15 }}>
                      <div
                        style={{
                          display: "flex",
                          alignItem: "center",
                          justifyContent: "center",
                        }}
                      >
                        <CardMedia
                          style={{
                            width: "100%",
                            maxHeight: "550px",
                          }}
                          component={item.type}
                          image={item.img}
                          controls
                          title={String(item.img)}
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div align="center">
                        <CardActions>
                          <Button
                            endIcon={<DeleteForeverIcon />}
                            label="DELETE"
                            color="secondary"
                            variant="contained"
                            onClick={() => deleteMedia(item.id)}
                          >
                            REMOVE
                          </Button>
                        </CardActions>
                      </div>
                    </Card>
                  </Grid>
                ))}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

The issue is a state mutation.

```
const [imageLinks, setImageLinks] = useState([]);
```

`tempLinks` is a reference to the `imageLinks` state. You are pushing directly into this `tempLinks` array and saving the same array reference back into state. The code is also incorrectly attempting to log the state immediately after enqueueing the state update. This doesn't work as React state updates are asynchronously processed.

```
if (r_json.success) {
  let tempLinks = imageLinks; // <-- reference to state
  tempLinks.push({            // <-- state mutation!
    img: r_json.image_url,
    id: r_json.m_id,
    type: r_json.m_type,
  });
  setImageLinks(tempLinks);   // <-- same reference back into state
  console.log(imageLinks);    // <-- only logs current state
}
```

The `imageLinks` state array reference never changes so React doesn't see this as state actually being updated.

## Solution

Create and return a ***new*** array reference for React.

```
if (r_json.success) {
  setImageLinks(imageLinks => [ // <-- new array reference
    ...imageLinks,              // <-- shallow copy previous state
    {                           // <-- append new element object
      img: r_json.image_url,
      id: r_json.m_id,
      type: r_json.m_type,
    }
  ]);
}
```

Use a separate `useEffect` hook to console log the state updates.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(imageLinks);
}, [imageLinks]);
```

Comment: That worked!  One thing I'm still confused about though, is that using my old bad method did add the files to the array, and did log the changes in the console, it just seemed like the Render component wouldn't actually recognize that until I changed another state value.
The way I had it, I could upload 10 pictures, on the site nothing would happen, but the console would log all 10 uploads being added to the array, and as soon as would change something else, all 10 photos would pop up.
I'm SUPER new to React.
HUGE thank you.

Comment: @JoesphStahLynn Uh, I guess I didn't explain the mutation part well enough. The code was mutating the current state, and you were logging the mutations, that is why it *looked* like your update was successful. You needed to make *some other* state update to trigger the component to rerender, thus exposing the mutated state after rerendering. React won't trigger rerendering on the mutation alone since the array reference didn't change.

Comment: No worries man, I'm also somewhat new to JavaScript, and recently watched a video that explained value vs reference, and that explained just about every object-based problem I was having.  Seriously though, thank you for the speedy response.